# If a function is not bounded away from zero, then integal of reciprocal diverges?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f$ is just some function $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, not necessarily continuous. When talking about the integral then I refer about the Lebesgue integral for more generality. Another assumption is that $f$ never reaches zero, or if you want, that $f\neq 0$ almost everywhere. Under these assumptions, is it always true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f^{-1}|=\infty$?

I am not sure if this is claim holds. I have tried the family of functions $e^{-a|x|}$, $e^{ax}$, for any positive $a$, and their inverses all diverged. So at least it seems to be true. Could you help me proving this or showing a counterexample? Thank yoou.

EDIT: By $f^{-1}$ I mean $\frac{1}{f}$.

Comment: Is $f^{-1}$ the inverse or the reciprocal?

Comment: The title says inverse so I posted an answer assuming that it is the inverse.  @Henry

Comment: My apologies, I meant the reciprocal. @Henry

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} -(1+x^2) & \text{if }\; x\leq -1, \\
-2\sqrt{-x} & \text{if }\; -1< x\leq 0,\\
2\sqrt{x} & \text{if }\; 0< x< 1,\\
1+x^2 & \text{if }\; x\geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
This function is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$, it is zero only at $x=0$, and the integral of $\frac{1}{|f(x)|}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is finite (it is $\frac{\pi}{2}+2$).

If by "Suppose $f$ is just some function $\mathbb{R}$ to itself" you just mean that the function is real valued but not necessarily surjective, just take $f(x)=1+x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\int_0^{x} \frac 1 {1+t^{4}}dt$. Then $f(x)\neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$ and $\int |f^{-1}(x)|dx=\int |y|f'(y)dy=\int \frac {|y|} {1+y^{4}}dy <\infty$